# Cambiar ajax en Datatable con evento .click Jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, datatables

Tengo una Datatable donde se muestra los totales calculados de la venta de concreto a lo largo de la semana. Los valores por default son 0 y mientras se guarden pedidos de concreto a lo largo de la semana los datos irán cambiando.

Esta es la vista general de la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el script que uso para insertar la informacion:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';
            var table = $('#m3_sem').DataTable( {

                "ajax": "dist/ajax/prueba_m3_sem.php",
                "paging":   false,
                "ordering": false,
                "info":     false,
                "searching": false,
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "resistencia" },
                    { "data": "res1" },
                    { "data": "res2" },
                    { "data": "res3" },
                    { "data": "res4" },
                    { "data": "res5" },
                    { "data": "res6" },
                    { "data": "total" }
                ],
                "order": [[0, 'asc']],
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "language": {
                    "sSearch" : "Buscar:",
                    "lengthMenu": "Mostrando _MENU_ registros por pagina",
                    "zeroRecords": "No hay pedidos pendientes",
                    "info": "Mostrando pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                    "infoEmpty": "Sin registros",
                    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros totales)",
                    "paginate" : {
                        "first" : "Primera pagina",
                        "previous" : "Anterior",
                        "next" : "Siguiente",
                        "last" : "Ultima pagina"
                    }
                }
            });

        } );
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de seleccionar un numero de la semana con un Select y haciendo click a un botón envie el numero de la semana por metodo POST a un archivo PHP para que lo reciba como parametro y al hacer la consulta de los datos para hacer los totales los filtre con el numero de la semana, despues borrar la información que ya esta y llenar la tabla con la nueva información que fue "filtrada" de acuerdo a la semana seleccionada. Tengo una idea general de como hacerla pero no se como vaciar la tabla y llenarla con la nueva información y es ahí donde necesito ayuda.

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

A la configuración del DataTable agregale la propiedad:

`data: function(d){
     d.fecha = $("#id_select_dia_semana").val();
}`

Abajo de la inicialización del DataTable agrega la función:

```
function actualizar(){
tabla.ajax.reload();
}
```

Y el botón podría quedar así:

```
<button onclick="actualizar()">Actualizar</button>
```

Al hacerlo así, cuando se llame la función `actualizar` se volverá a realizar la petición ajax y llevará el parámetro `fecha` con el valor que se ha seleccionado en el select con id `id_select_dia_semana`

Comment: Deberia quedar asi?:
https://jsfiddle.net/9wsrv7k6/

Comment: Sí, eso debería funcionar

Comment: Oh ok, ya entendi tu propuesta, pero asi puedo mandar el numero de la semana por post al archivo php?

Comment: Sí,  si abres la consola de desarrollador del navegador y haces la solitud verás el parámetro sem con el valor de la semana elegida en el select